# Converting literate Haskell (.lhs) to Haskell (.hs)

Tags: haskell, literate-programming

Is there an easy way to convert a literate Haskell file (`.lhs`) to a regular Haskell (`.hs`) source file?

I thought there might be a GHC option, but the GHC manual doesn't seem to have much information on literate programs or the `.lhs` format.  The word "literate" doesn't even appear in the index!

The [Literate programming](https://wiki.haskell.org/Literate_programming) link on the Wiki includes links to scripts that convert between "bird" and "`\begin{code}`..`\end{code}`" styles or convert `.lhs` to TeX format, but that's it.

Comment: Why is this question off topic? It is clear and concise, and is certainly practical and answerable. I also think that the syntax and semantics of literate haskell files is very much within the scope of "questions about Haskell"

Answer (score 8):

GHC itself uses a standalone C program called `unlit` to process `.lhs` files.  You can probably find it installed somewhere in your GHC installation.  If you run it, it shows a few command line options without explanation:

```
$ cd ~/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.6.4/lib/ghc-8.6.4/bin
$ ./unlit
usage: unlit [-q] [-n] [-c] [-#] [-P] [-h label] file1 file2
```

Digging into the source code, it looks like the options are:

```
-q   "quiet": ignore certain errors, so permit missing empty lines before and after
     "bird" style and accept completely empty programs
-n   (default) "noisy": opposite of -q, so be noisy about errors
-c   "crunch": don't leave blank lines where literate comments are removed
-#   delete lines that start with "#!"
-P   suppress CPP line number pragma, but only matters if `-h` is supplied
-h   File name for an initial `#line` pragma
```

So, the command line:

```
$ /path/to/unlit -c myfile.lhs myfile.hs
```

will probably do a good job converting `myfile.lhs`:

```
This is a literate program

> main :: IO ()

using both code styles
\begin{code}
  main = putStrLn "hello"
\end{code}
```

to an "illiterate" program `myfile.hs`:

```
  main :: IO ()
  main = putStrLn "hello"
```

For "bird" style, it actually replaces the '>' character with a space and leaves the rest of the indentation in place, so for my example above, both lines in `myfile.hs` are indented with two spaces, which could be a drawback.

Answer (score 0):

Just hack together a quick script like the one below :)
This converts the literate parts to line-comments.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns #-}

import Control.Monad (forM_)
import System.FilePath.Glob (glob)
import qualified Data.Text as T
import qualified Data.Text.IO as T
import System.FilePath (replaceExtension)
import Development.Shake.Command

unLiterateHaskell :: T.Text -> T.Text
unLiterateHaskell = T.unlines . map processLine . T.lines

processLine :: T.Text -> T.Text
processLine (T.stripEnd -> txt) = case T.uncons txt of
  Nothing -> txt
  Just ('>', txt) -> T.drop 1 txt -- may need to adjust here depending on style
  Just{} -> "-- " <> txt

main :: IO ()
main = do
  files <- glob "**/*.lhs"
  forM_ files $ \f -> do
    src <- T.readFile f
    T.writeFile (replaceExtension f "hs") (unLiterateHaskell src)
    Exit _ <- cmd ("mv" :: String) f (f <> ".bak")
    pure ()
```